# +Moving CodeIgniter from live to local

Tags: codeigniter, calendar, backend

Perhaps someone can share their experience or advise on how to get this accomplished.
I have looked around and found only a wiki entry dealing with server migration from host to host.
Here is the setup and things I have tried:

- locally I am running win 10 with XAMPP server
- hosted on hostgator

  1. Downloaded all files from live site
  2. Did an SQL dump/import onto my local mySQL
  3. Edited ‘exp_sites’ for paths and URLs
  4. Edited ‘config.php’ in system folder

Result:
- can not login into backend ...that is form refreshes but no redirect. I can tell that db is being queried since since I do get error back if it is a wrong password.
Anyone has done similar setups/downloads/takve-overs of their client’s site?

Ideally, I would just like the access to CP so I can edit the settings/paths of weblogs,uploads etc.
Thanks for your time!

Comment: `config.php` in system folder? It's usually in `application/config/config.php`. What's 'exp_sites'? Must be custom to your application.

Comment: Have you changed values in `APPPATH.'config/database.php'`?

Answer (score 1):

Are you using CI default password library for password creation? If you are using then these passwords will not work for you because this library generate server dependent passwords.